# restore dump com nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

Preciso **restaurar um banco de dados postgres** com nodejs...

Minha rotina faz o download do ultimo backup (custom dump) pelo ftp, e cria o banco (sem a estrutura).

Agora preciso executar esse arquivo que fiz o download para restaurar o banco. Mas não sei como.

Pensei que só era só ler o conteúdo do arquivo e executar como uma query, mas não. Também não encontrei nenhuma lib ou exemplo para isso.

Preciso de exemplos ou alguma idéia de como fazer isso...

Comment: Windows ou Linux?

Comment: Para os 2 ambientes.

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 0):

No `Node.js` você pode executar uma aplicação externa. Neste caso usaremos o módulo [`child_process`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) para executar o [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/app-psql.html) e despejar o conteúdo no novo banco:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const { createReadStream } = require('fs');

const restaurar = (destino, origem) => {
  console.time('Despejando conteúdo.');
  // Cria o banco de dados
  const child = spawn('createdb', [destino]);

  child.on('exit', () => {
    const conteudo = createReadStream(origem);
    const psql = spawn('psql', [destino]);
    conteudo.pipe(psql.stdin);
    console.timeEnd('Despejando conteúdo.');
  });
};
```

> [`child_process`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)
>
> The [`child_process`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module provides the ability to spawn child processes in a manner that is similar, but not identical, to [`popen(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html).

Em tradução livre:

> O módulo [`child_process`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) provê a habilidade de executar processos filhos de uma maneira similar, mas não idêntica, ao [`popen(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html).